# how does osgi security model work?

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, securitymanager

I would like to know how exactly OSGI can check their own Permissions like PackagePermission. I have read that they use a self-made ProtectionDomain but that is not true (for the new releases I was looking at). It would be ok if you just refer to Equinox. 
Would the implementation check befor every bundle exports its resources for a PackagePermission like that?

```
 public void export(BundleContext ctx) {
        SecurityManager manager = System.getSecurityManager();
        if(manager != null) {
            manager.checkPermission(new PackagePermission(ctx, "export"));
        }
 }
```

'cause i thought that it isn't quiet easy to check such self-made permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course look in the source code of Equinox or Apache Felix Security to see how this is done :-) For package permissions, the framework will probably use [Bundle.hasPermission](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#hasPermission%28java.lang.Object%29) to avoid the thrown exception.

Comment: I already looked at it, but missed the [Bundle.hasPermission](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#hasPermission%28java.lang.Object%29) method. Thanks :D

Comment: I couldn't find anything special. The SecurityManager that is used looks quiet normal...